# Iphone UITableview Custom cell button click and didSelect method

Tags: iphone

in my app there are a custom cell which have a button with some action as well as i must perfrom didSelectRowAtIndexPath method my button action doesn't perform beacuse of didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

My code is given below->

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(DriverListCell *)cell  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.fromLbl.text=[[jobArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"pickup_addr"];
    cell.toLbl.text=[[jobArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"deliver_address"];
    [cell.arrowBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(moreInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
-(void)moreInfo:(UIButton*)sender
{
   NSLog(@"more info Clicked");
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSLog(@"whole row selected");
}
```

Can I perform both action simultaneously? Or give me some idea to solve problem.

I must have perform both action one on custom cell button click and other on whole row selection.

Comment: set the frame of button in such a size that button click takes effect.

Comment: If you have a uibutton on uicellview then uibutton click event will be fired when it is clicked. Cell's didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not be fired.

Comment: when i click on button it call didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Now its working i created a button programmatically then its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If button will be clicked `-(void)moreInfo:(UIButton*)sender` this function will be called.

But if you select the cell `didselectrowatindexpath` function will be called.

In order to perform both action simultaneously remove your uibutton and then call `-(void)moreInfo:(int)index` function from `didselectrowatindexpath` method, to perform both actions at the same time.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(DriverListCell *)cell  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.fromLbl.text=[[jobArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"pickup_addr"];
    cell.toLbl.text=[[jobArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"deliver_address"];
}

-(void)moreInfo:(int)index
{
    NSLog(@"more info Clicked");
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self moreInfo:indexpath.row];
    NSLog(@"whole row selected");
}
```

Comment: this calls both method called one by one but i have to call only one method based on button click or row select

Comment: Then your code is fine. check your cell xib you have correctly attach uibutton with an instance arrowBtn. OR your UIbutton is not behind any other view/label

Comment: i am calling method via code                            [cell.arrowBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(moreInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Check referencing Outlet of UIButton. Is it arrowBtn?. Check the position of UIButton. Is it behind any UILabel or any other UIView ?

Comment: yes referencing Outlet of UIButton is arrowBtn. and button is under the main UIView at last

Comment: Then your code is just fine. Increase the frame size of uibutton and recheck.

Comment: which frame i also increase the button size

Comment: Try the same thing in this function : - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath . Last suggestion from myside :)

Comment: Now its working i created a button programmatically then its working fine